# Transfer settings from SwfObject to Jquery SwfObject?

Tags: jquery, swfobject

Does somebody know how you transfer the settings from SwfObject to Jquery SwfObject?
I cant find the right documentation for this.
I know it uses the dimensions of the div but that's no problem.

Jquery original SwfObject:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var flashvars = {};
    flashvars.xmlPath = 'stripped_images.xml';
    var params = {};
    params.scale = "noscale";
    params.salign = "tl";
    params.bgcolor = "#000000";
    params.allowfullscreen = "true";
    params.allowscriptaccess = "always";
    params.wmode = "opaque";
    var attributes = {};
    swfobject.embedSWF("main_stripped.swf?" + Math.round(Math.random() * 10000), "myContent", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
```

The new Jquery SwfObject:

```
FlashBackground = $.flash.create(
{
    swf: 'main_stripped.swf',
    params: {
    scale : "noscale",
    salign : "tl",
    bgcolor : "#000000",
    allowfullscreen : "true",
    allowscriptaccess : "always",
    wmode : "opaque"
    },
    flashvars: {
        xmlPath : 'stripped_images.xml',
    },
    attributes: {
    ?
    }   
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is right. You aren't using any attributes in the original, so you wouldn't with the plugin.